# Testing of console tools

Tags: automated-testing, python

From my previous experience, I am used to write tests for either unit testing or integration/deployment testing.

Now I am facing the challenge to write automated tests for a console tool using a cloud API written in Python where the following aspects are new to me:

- Test combinations of non-interactive branched switches
- Test user interaction (input, selection)

So am not sure what is the most efficient way to organize my testing, whether there is more to it in this specific case.

So far, I consider to focus on non-interactive calls and validate not the output of the tool but the state changes in the cloud. Using unit tests as I know them should be okay for that?

Comment: [refer this](https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/app-testing/desktop/console/interacting-with.html)